# How to deploy a AWS Lambda Function conditionally, using Serverless Framework, only to prd stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

thank you for taking the time to read this post. I’m trying to deploy an AWS Lambda Function conditionally, based on stage (only for “prd” stage).

This lambda has a Role, which deploys conditionally too. I already achieved this by using cloudformation conditions on the resources block, as shown below:

[image]

[image]

However, I don’t know how to make it work for the lambda function, as it is in the functions block I don’t have idea how to reference the condition. From the serverless.yml reference I decided to do what is shown below, and it doesn’t work:

[image]

Can someone help me to understand what am I doing wrong? And also what would be the solution to make this work? Thanks in advance

Comment: You may try to use JS to resolve enabled/disabled state as described in https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-in-javascript-files. I managed to disable some plug-ins for local stage (e.g. when using LocalStack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using the serverless if-else plugin
https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-ifelse

You can use the plugin by adding them to your plugin section of the serverless.yml

```
plugins:
 - serverless-plugin-ifelse
```

and set up conditions to update values in the serverless.yml for the functions and exclude them.
The include option isn't available, so your condition would be something like -

```
custom:
  currentStage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  serverlessIfElse:
      - If: '"${self:provider.stage}" == "prd"'
        Set:
          functions.startXtractUniversalInstance.role: <custom role for prod>
        ElseExclude:
          - functions.startXtractUniversalInstance
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I solved it by adding the Lambda Function on the Resources section of the template. Even though your solution also work, I wonder how would work or what would be the syntax of the condition clause in the functions block. Hope someone find it out. Thank you friend

Comment: Well. Declaring Lambda functions in the resources section kinda defeats the purpose of using the serverless framework.
The condition is declared as I have mentioned in the post above.
serverless would evaluate this condition before execution.
So you don't have to specify anything in the function section of the yaml. 
the condition would exclude this function entirely if true, i.e when stage is 'prd'

Comment: You are right mate, that's exactly what I though. It removes the benefits of providing lambda functions from serverless. Your solution works very well, I'll definitely use it. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

if you check the [`serverless.yml`](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/) reference, there's no support for "conditions" key in the lambda

**Serverless Framework definitions ARE NOT a 1:1 to CloudFormation**

you can override the AWS CloudFormation resource generated by Serverless, to apply your own options, [link here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/#override-aws-cloudformation-resource)

which more or less would look like this:

```yaml
functions:
  startXtractUniversalInstance:
  ...

resources:
  extensions:
    StartXtractUniversalInstanceFunction:
      Condition: ...
```

make sure to double check the name generated to your function, the above `StartXtractUniversalInstanceFunction` could be wrong

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your answer. In that serverless.yml reference, if you go to the "functions" block, you'll find a "condition" clause right below "layers" and "tracing". I though that there was a way to use it, maybe something similar to CloudFormation.

It says explicitly ---> "condition: SomeCondition # optional, adds 'Condition' clause".

I solved it by providing a lambda function via cloudformation resources, but I would like to know why I'm not able to use that clause in the functions block. Thanks in advance